# Flexible size UICollectionview Footer not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been working on a UI screen where I need to fill up screen with fetched data from API and show view at very bottom of the screen.

My screen contains data in scrollable fashion so I have to use UICollectionView to manage this scrollable content properly.

i.e. If more content then footer will be shown at end of UICollectionView after whole list scroll is over, if less content then footer will be show at very bottom of the screen leaving blank space between footer and content.

Following is my code where I have dynamic flow layout which changes based on data I get.

*API Function:*

```
private func fetchEventDetails(_ eventId: Int) {
    {
    API Call - Success 
    }
    self.contentItem = response
                
} onFailure: { error in
    {
    API Call - Failure
    }
}
```

ContentItem is a variable stores API data and loads them into UICollectionView. So, whenever contentItem is set, new flowLayout is generated and Collection view is being re-rendered.

```
var contentItem: LSTEventDetails? {
    didSet {
        updateCollectionViewLayout()
    }
}

private func updateCollectionViewLayout() {
    CollectionView.collectionViewLayout = <generateNewFlowLayout()>
    CollectionView.reloadData()
    
    CollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    CollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Above function assigns new Flow layout to collection view and we have written resize footer view related function in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so, layout methods are called here. I don't know best place where to call this resizeFooter function which can be executed once data is loaded.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    if CollectionView.numberOfSections > 0 {
        //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.CollectionView.resizeStickyFooter(for: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), andSectionLayout: self.sectionLayouts, andView: self.view)
        //}
    }
}
```

In the above function, if I add `asyncAfter` I get some jerky animation, like all data is loaded and then after sometime, the footer jumps to correct position which seems a bit weird.

`sectionLayouts` holds reference to all `NSCollectionLayoutSection` sections which I create while generating flow layout.

The main resizeFooter function is added as extension to UICollectionView:

extension UICollectionView {

```
    func resizeStickyFooter(for indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), andSectionLayout sectionLayouts: [NSCollectionLayoutSection]?, andView view: UIView) {
        let size = self.bounds.size.height - self.contentInset.bottom//- (sectionLayouts?.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.contentInsets.top + $1.contentInsets.bottom }) ?? 0) // - LSTTheme.UI.TabBarSize - no need as tab is hidden
        let layoutViewSize = self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
        
        if layoutViewSize.height < size {
            if let footerView = self.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, at: indexPath) {
                
                let footerHeight = size - layoutViewSize.height
                let footerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                    heightDimension: .absolute(max(0, footerHeight) + footerView.bounds.height)
                )
                let sectionFooter = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
                    layoutSize: footerSize,
                    elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter,
                    alignment: .bottom
                )
                
                if (indexPath.section < (sectionLayouts?.count ?? 0)),
                   let layouts = sectionLayouts {
                    
                    let section = layouts[indexPath.section]
                    
                    section.boundarySupplementaryItems.removeAll(where: {$0.elementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter} )
                    section.boundarySupplementaryItems.append(sectionFooter)
                    
                    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, env in
                        return layouts[sectionIndex]
                    }
                    self.collectionViewLayout = layout
                    
                    self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here, when this function gets executed at first time, I am not getting proper footer size and collectionViewContentSize.

Like, for the first time when this screen is loaded, I get following data listed on left-side while when I do some action on that particular screen by tapping button and which in turn calls `updateCollectionViewLayout()` again to create new flow layout and execute resize footer from viewDidLayoutSubviews(), I get following data listed on right-side.

```
size = 656                             VS     size = 656
layoutViewSize = (375.0, 414.0)        |      layoutViewSize = (375.0, 576.33)
  - width : 375.0                      |        - width : 375.0
  - height : 414.0                     |        - height : 576.33
                                       |
footerView = (0 394; 375 20);          |      footerView = (0 499.333; 375 77);
  - height : 20                        |        - height : 77
                                       |
So, footerSize = {1, 262}              |      So, footerSize = {1, 156.66}
  - height : 262                       |        - height : 156.66
```

Here, you will be able to see difference in layoutViewSize and footerView both which in turn affects footerSize.

Would anyone suggest me better option where to call resizeFooter method, so, I get proper contentViewSize once data is loaded? But I don't want that kind of jumpy solution where footer jumps to its original size post loading of all data.

*ViewDidLoad() method just has call to fetchData API and nothing else, so, anything in viewDidLoad does not affect the collectionview.*

I want it to be seamless so UX can not be affected.

Please provide me any suggestion.

Comment: I hope to get some suggestion on this if there is anything I can improve.